# NameError: name 'net' is not defined

Tags: python, pytorch

NMTの学習について、以下のコードで画像のようなエラーが出ます。
検索しても自身で解決できない状態です。
解決方法などお分かりなる方、ご回答の方よろしくお願いいたします。

```
net.train()
for epoch in range(20): #20エポックまで学習
    loss1K = 0.0
    for i in range(len(jdata)):
        jinput = torch.LongTensor([jdata[i][1:]]).to(device)
        einput = torch.LongTensor([edata[i][:-1]]).to(device)
        out = net(jinput, einput)
        gans = torch.LongTensor([ edata[i][1:] ]).to(device)
        loss = criterion(out[0],gans[0])
        loss1K += loss.item()
        if (i % 100 ==0):
            print(epoch, i, loss1K)
            loss1K = 0.0
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        outfile = "nmt-" + str(epoch) + ".model"
        torch.save(net.state_dict(),outfile)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `NameError:` 名前「`net`」が定義されていない, というメッセージ。なので定義するとよいでしょう。[pytorch tutorials beginner](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) を見るとモデルクラスを指定するはずでは？

Comment: @oriri class MyNMT(nn.Module):を指定しているのですが、それとは別でモデルクラスを指定すると言うことでしょうか？

Comment: 質問のソースにその部分を記したほうがよいでしょう(ソースコードが足りない)。また (その場合) `net = MyNMT()` が行われていないからこそエラーメッセージ出てるのでは？